# ¿como configuro regla firestore para borrado?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Buen dia, estoy con reglas de firestore, para la creación me funciona pero para el borrado no, aunque según yo debería ser lo mismo, lo que intento hacer es que solo permita crear y borrar documentos si el documento contiene en un campo el ID del usuario autenticado o bien si es un usuario que sea Admin, no entiendo por que para crear si me funciona pero para borrar me marca error :( ¿que cambia para el borrado?

Aquí el ejemplo, repito el write funciona, el delete no :(

```
match /pagos/{year}/pagos/{id} {
allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.alumnoId || 
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;

allow delete: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.alumnoId || 
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podés intentar con lo siguiente borrando la segunda regla y haciendo una sola para los dos operaciones

```
match /pagos/{year}/pagos/{id} {
allow write,delete: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.alumnoId || 
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
```